# @Inject field during test phase

Tags: java, maven, log4j, cdi

I'm adding logging functionality to my application and I'm using `slf4j` implemented by `log4j`. To simplify my code I have a helper class to produce a logger (the idea is not mine, I took it from [Beginning Java EE 7 by Antonio Goncalves](http://www.apress.com/9781430246268)), the class is like this:

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class LoggerProducer {

    @Produces
    public Logger createLogger(InjectionPoint injPoint) {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass());
    }
}
```

So in my classes all I have to do (in theory) is:

```
public class SomeClass {
    @Inject private Logger logger; // this could be private or default, doesn't matter
}
```

The problem is that during test phase I don't have CDI enabled because I'm running the code outside the container. I can't inject manually because I have some abstract classes with their own logger, so I can't instantiate that class and assign it a `Logger` instance.

Is there any way to "enable" CDI during test phase? My project is built with Maven and I'll be deploying to a Wildfly 10 Server. Thanks in advance for your answers.

### Note

I cannot do something like

```
public class SomeClassTest {
    private SomeClass someClass; // this is the class I want to test

    @Before
    public void init() {
        someClass.logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest(){...}
}
```

because I have some abstract classes with their own private `Logger logger` property and I need to keep it that way (I can't declare it `protected` ) because I want to keep a trace of where a message is thrown, so I need to keep the logger private. E.g. I have something like

```
public abstract class MyAbstract {
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;
}

public class MyConcrete extends MyAbstract {
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;
}
```

I could, from the test class, set `MyConcrete.logger` as default but I can`t do that for`MyAbstract.logger`because they are in different packages and I can't instantiate`MyAbstract`, am I explaining correctly?

### Note 2

My project structure is something like this:

```
package common

import org.slf4j.logger
...

public abstract class Generic {
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    public void doSomethingGeneric(){
        // do something and log it
    }
}

package specific

import ...

public class Concrete extends Generic{
    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    // some concrete methods...
}

package specific

public class ConcreteTest {
    private Concrete concrete;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        concrete = new Concrete();
        concrete.logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Concrete.class); // Dependency injection by hand
    }

    // some @Test methods
}
```

Eventually, a `@Test` method from `ConcreteTest` calls `Concrete.doSomethingGeneric()` as it's inherited to the `concrete` instance. The problem is that `doSomethingGeneric()` logs with the `Generic` logger and I don't know how to satisfy that dependency in a clean way (I prefer not to hack my code with setter methods unnecessary for production)

Comment: Well there's http://arquillian.org/, [DeltaSpike Test Control](http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/test-control.html), and http://jglue.org/cdi-unit/ as a few ways to do this.

Comment: "during test phase": Do you mean running Unit-Tests by JUnit?

Comment: @Heri, that's correct. I mean during running all my `@Test` methods in `src/test/java`

Comment: @JohnAment, AFAIK, Arquillian is for Integration tests (test within the container); the other two artifacts are for writing CDI-based test. Neither are my case. I just want to get an instance of  `Logger` during test phase

Comment: If you using spring the annotation @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) would help, probably followed by the annotation @ContextConfiguration(classes={ MyConfigClass1.class, MyConfigClass2.class }). I dont know if there alternatives without spring.

Comment: @AlvaroPedraza Arquillian can run against OWB and Weld, which is a common pattern to use for unit testing.  I'm confused then by your question, since your'e asking to "enable" CDI in your test phase.  But you only want to satisfy your logger??

Comment: @JohnAment, that's correct, I need to satisfy my logger (created with `@Produces` method) in my concrete and abstract classes, that's why I wrote *"enable"* (in quotes). The real problem is in my abstract class because I can't reference the logger from my test class. I believe there must be a clean way to accomplish this, without writing setter methods which I'll never use in production. Check **Note 2**, I added some info to clarify

Comment: @AlvaroPedraza you were presented with ways to enable CDI.  Can you clarify why this isn't what you want?

Comment: @JohnAment because I thought there could be a way to satisfy that dependency. In fact, I have some other `@Inject`ed properties but until now I was satisfying them by hand, but I can't do it with the Abstract's logger property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, using mockito test units:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyBeanTest {

  @Spy
  private Logger logger = LoggerProducer.getLogger();

  @InjectMocks
  private MyBean myTestBean; // = new MyBean(parameters). explicit if no default constructir

  @Test
  public void verifySomeLogic() {
    myTestBean.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Here, the mockito runtime and proxy will manage the injection, and you can even do verification on the logger itself.